# Setting an audience from declarative WebPart?

Tags: web-part, development, feature, audience-targeting

I have a module that deploys some page.

I'm adding webparts to these page, using a `<AllUsersWebPart>` node within a `<View>`:

```
  <View WebPartZoneID="Body"
        WebPartOrder="5"
        List="Lists/mylist"
        BaseViewID="4"
        Name="My Title">
    <![CDATA[
<webParts>
    <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
        <metaData>
            <type name="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart,Microsoft.SharePoint,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
            <importErrorMessage>Cannot import this Web Part.</importErrorMessage>
        </metaData>
        <data>
            <properties>
              <property name="Title" type="string">My title</property>
              <property name="AllowHide">False</property>
              <property name="AllowMinimize">False</property>
              <property name="AuthorizationFilter">;;;;MySharepointGroup</property>
              <property name="IsIncludedFilter">;;;;MySharepointGroup</property>
            </properties>
        </data>
    </webPart>
</webParts>
            ]]>
  </View>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to set the audience of the webpart to a specific SharePoint group, but this does not works as expected.

If I:

- don't include neither `AuthorizationFilter` nor `IsIncludedFilter`, the webpart is displaying as I expect, but for all users
- include `AuthorizationFilter` but not `IsIncludedFilter`, the webpart is displaying as I expect, but still for all users.
- include both `AuthorizationFilter` and `IsIncludedFilter`. this time, the webpart is in error, with this error :

> [WebPartPageUserException: The file format is not valid. Try importing a Web Part file (.WebPart).]
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartImporter.CreateWebPart(Boolean clearConnections) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartImporter.Import(SPWebPartManager manager, XmlReader reader, Boolean clearConnections, Uri webPartPageUri, SPWeb spWeb) 
>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.CompressWebPartNoSave(Boolean isClosed)

In the ULS log, there is exactly the same message, with no more error or warning.

I know I could set this audience from code, but I'd like keep my full declarative model.

What is the correct way to setup audience from xml ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I set up the audiences from a feature receiver.

Comment: Yup, that's what I ended up with as well

Answer (score 0):

i know it is a bit late but i was just involved in a similar Scenario:
I used the MembersWebPart in SharePoint 2013 and this is a working example:

```
<WebPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v2">
    <Assembly>Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c</Assembly>
    <TypeName>Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.MembersWebPart</TypeName>
    <Title>$Resources:core,MembersWebPartTitle;</Title>
    <Description>$Resources:core,MembersWebPartDescription;</Description>
    <PartImageLarge>/_layouts/15/images/msmeml.gif</PartImageLarge>
    <AuthorizationFilter>;;;;Besitzer</AuthorizationFilter>
    <IsIncludedFilter>;;;;Besitzer</IsIncludedFilter>
</WebPart>
```

Ronny